# asynchronous python itertools chain multiple generators

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, python-asyncio, sequence-generators

**UPDATED QUESTION FOR CLARITY:**

suppose I have 2 processing generator functions:

```
def gen1(): # just for examples,
  yield 1   # yields actually carry 
  yield 2   # different computation weight 
  yield 3   # in my case

def gen2():
  yield 4
  yield 5
  yield 6
```

I can chain them with itertools

```
from itertools import chain

mix = chain(gen1(), gen2())
```

and then I can create another generator function object with it,

```
def mix_yield():
   for item in mix:
      yield item
```

or simply if I just want to `next(mix)`, it's there.

**My question is, how can I do the equivalent in asynchronous code?**

Because I need it to:

- return in yield (one by one), or with `next` iterator
- the fastest resolved yield first (async)

**PREV. UPDATE:**

After experimenting and researching, I found [aiostream](https://aiostream.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) library which states as async version of itertools, so what I did:

```
import asyncio
from aiostream import stream

async def gen1(): 
     await asyncio.sleep(0) 
     yield 1 
     await asyncio.sleep(0) 
     yield 2 
     await asyncio.sleep(0) 
     yield 3 

async def gen2(): 
     await asyncio.sleep(0) 
     yield 4 
     await asyncio.sleep(0) 
     yield 5 
     await asyncio.sleep(0) 
     yield 6 

a_mix = stream.combine.merge(gen1(),gen2())

async def a_mix_yield():
   for item in a_mix:
      yield item
```

but I still can't do `next(a_mix)`

```
TypeError: 'merge' object is not an iterator
```

or `next(await a_mix)`

```
raise StreamEmpty()
```

Although I still can make it into a list:

```
print(await stream.list(a_mix))
# [1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 6]
```

so one goal is completed, one more to go:

- return in yield (one by one), or with `next` iterator

  <del>- the fastest resolved yield first (async)</del>

Comment: Your code above is just creating a couple generators and iterating through them.  Hence why you are seeing them printed in order.  You could iterate through gen2 first and it would print 4,5,6,1,2,3.  Perhaps you should find a different example to show what you're trying to do.

Comment: In my case gen1() and gen2() yields not at the same time, I will update my question and I think already found the answer with aiostream (I hope).

Comment: Sorry people for the confusion, I updated the question for clarity.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Python's [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) built-in function is just a convenient way of invoking the underlying `__next__` method on the object. The async equivalent of `__next__` is the `__anext__` method on the async iterator. There is no `anext` global function in the standard library (the [aiostream](https://github.com/vxgmichel/aiostream) library [provides one](https://aiostream.readthedocs.io/en/stable/utilities.html#aiostream.aiter_utils.anext)), but one could easily write it:

```
async def anext(aiterator):
    return await aiterator.__anext__()
```

But the savings is so small that, in rare situations when this is needed, one may as well invoke `__anext__` directly. The async iterator is in turn obtained from an async *iterable* by calling the `__aiter__` (in analogy to `__iter__` provided by regular iterables). Async iteration driven manually looks like this:

```
a_iterator = obj.__aiter__()          # regular method
elem1 = await a_iterator.__anext__()  # async method
elem2 = await a_iterator.__anext__()  # async method
...
```

`__anext__` will raise `StopAsyncIteration` when no more elements are available. To loop over async iterators one should use `async for`.

Here is a runnable example, based on your code, using both `__anext__` and `async for` to exhaust the stream set up with `aiostream.stream.combine.merge`:

```
async def main():
    a_mix = stream.combine.merge(gen1(), gen2())
    async with a_mix.stream() as streamer:
        mix_iter = streamer.__aiter__()    
        print(await mix_iter.__anext__())
        print(await mix_iter.__anext__())
        print('remaining:')
        async for x in mix_iter:
            print(x)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I have to re-read it multiple times and connect the dots before completely understand.

Comment: @Ardhi Another good resource is [the PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0525/#support-for-asynchronous-iteration-protocol) that introduced them.

Comment: Just mentioning that entering a streaming context in aiostream is meant to be done using `async with zs.stream() as streamer:`, as seen in this [demonstration](https://aiostream.readthedocs.io/en/latest/presentation.html#demonstration).

Comment: @Vincent Thanks, I've now amended the answer to use the advertised pattern.

Comment: +1. One potential improvement to this answer would be to highlight how easily you can make an `async` equivalent of `next` given this knowledge - something like `async def anext(async_iterator): return await async_iterator.__anext__()`

Answer (score 2):

I came across this answer and I looked at the aiostream library. Here is the code I came up with to merge multiple async generators. It does not use any library.

```
async def merge_generators(gens:Set[AsyncGenerator[Any, None]]) -> AsyncGenerator[Any, None]:
    pending = gens.copy()
    pending_tasks = { asyncio.ensure_future(g.__anext__()): g for g in pending }
    while len(pending_tasks) > 0:
        done, _ = await asyncio.wait(pending_tasks.keys(), return_when="FIRST_COMPLETED")
        for d in done:
            try:
                result = d.result()
                yield result
                dg = pending_tasks[d]
                pending_tasks[asyncio.ensure_future(dg.__anext__())] = dg
            except StopAsyncIteration as sai:
                print("Exception in getting result", sai)
            finally:
                del pending_tasks[d]
```

Hope this helps you and let me know if there are any bugs in this.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to merge and chain several async generators with these simple helpers.

Different error strategies can be applied so I choose not to show any error
For clarity I don't show error handling as different

```py
import asyncio


async def merge(*streams):
    n = len(streams)
    queue = asyncio.Queue()
    signal = object()
    async def enqueue(stream):
        async for event in stream:
            await queue.put(event)
        await queue.put(signal)
    tasks = [asyncio.create_task(enqueue(stream)) for stream in streams]
    while n > 0:
        event = await queue.get()
        if event is signal:
            n -= 1
        else:
            yield event
    await asyncio.wait(tasks)


async def chain(*streams):
    for stream in streams:
        async for item in stream:
            yield item
```

Example usage:

```py
async def gen(name, n, nap):
    for i in range(n):
        await asyncio.sleep(nap)
        yield f"Event #{i} for {name}"


async def main():
    print("Merging 2 async generators")
    g1 = gen("task A", 3, 0.5)
    g2 = gen("task B", 6, 0.3)
    async for item in merge(g1, g2):
        print(f"  {item}")

    print("Chaining 2 async generators")
    g1 = gen("task A", 3, 0.5)
    g2 = gen("task B", 6, 0.3)
    async for item in chain(g1, g2):
        print(f"  {item}")
```